# Baking multiple objects to keyframes resets their orientation by their origins

Tags: physics, baking

[image: Before and After Screenshot]

I made a breakable object and the simulation is fine. But when I bake the simulation all the pieces of the breakable object just stack in the same place in space.

The pieces are driven by a cube the first 60 frames, then the simulation makes the rest.

*.blend* in a zip file: https://copy.com/qo3Rx2dNz0xn

Comment: Could you upload your .blend or some screenshots?

Comment: Hi, thanks for viewing my question, here is a link for the blend file you require, is a zip file:

https://copy.com/qo3Rx2dNz0xn

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer.

- First, the steps that caused the problem:

  After breaking the object using the cell fracture addon, I needed the physics of all the 700 pieces to be driven by an animation (they where parented to a cube which has keyframes to make everything "fall" in one piece).
  Then I keyframed the physics of one piece (1), but there where like 700 objects that I wanted to have that same behavior so to copy those keyframes I read that I just needed to **link the animation data** as I did (2).
- How I found the problem:

  An action was shared linked by 757 objects (3).
- Solution:

  So I selected my group of pieces, hit <kbd>U</kbd> to unlink the animation data (4) and then I baked the animation and everythig was *almost fine*. I didn't knew why but I simply had to **unparent** all the shards.

[image: Step by Step explanation]

Answer (score 0):

Making the objects "Single User" seems to fix it, in Blender 2.92 you do this by selecting all the objects you want to bake to keyframes in object mode, then go to "Object"->"Relations"->"Object Animation"
[image: step by step gif]